# ReactNative error onPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

on clicking the text, i get an error saying "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.categoryClicked.bind')"

I think the error is "onPress={()=>this.categoryClicked.bind(this)}" there must be a different way to call the categoryClicked function when the button is clicked. What is wrong in my code ?

```
class CategoriesView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

categoryClicked(){
    this.props.categoryPressed(this.props.Category);
}

renderSubCategory(){
    return(
        this.props.Category.sub_category.map(function(subCategory, i){
            return(
                <View style={styles.abcd}>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.categoryClicked.bind(this)}>
                        <Text>{subCategory.title}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            )
        })
    )
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={styles.avf}>
                <Text>{this.props.Category.heading}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.ddd}>
                {this.renderSubCategory()}
            </View>
        </View>
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: try to call your function like : `onPress={this.categoryClicked.bind(this)}` instead of `onPress={() => this.categoryClicked.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is `onPress={this.categoryClicked.bind(this)}` instead of an arrow function. `.bind(this)` returns a function with the context correctly binded to `this`, therefore, it does not get invoked.

Also, I suggest putting the binding in constructor, as you don't want the binding to happen every time the component re-renders.
e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.categoryClicked = this.categoryClicked.bind(this);
}
```

Then just use `onPress={this.categoryClicked}`

If you want to pass down `sub-category`, you can do

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.subcategoryClicked = props.Category.sub_categories.map(sub_category => this.categoryClicked.bind(this, sub_category));
}
```

then use like this in `render`:

```
this.props.Category.sub_category.map(function(subCategory, i) {
  <View style={styles.abcd}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.subcategoryClicked[i]}>
      <Text>{subCategory.title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
```

P.S, I am not sure if this is a good pattern to follow. Stick to `this.categoryClicked(bind, subcategory)` if you are not comfortable with doing this. This is one of those things that I am not sure if the optimization is worth it.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Can you explain how can i put the binding in constructor. and how would it help, I am new to react-native and did not understand what you mean by "you don't want the binding to happen every time the component re-renders."

Comment: So every time the component re-render, it will call the render function. Therefore, `this.categoryClicked.bind(this)` will be called every time the component re-renders. If you put it in the constructor, this will only have one time when the component is created. To do so, do `constructor(props) { super(props); this.categoryClicked = this.categoryClicked.bind(this); }`. Then in render just do `onPress={this.categoryClicked}`

Comment: Also, I want to add that [@Dhiraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261684/4655003) should help you if instead, what you want to pass to `categoryPressed` is the sub-category instead of the main category.

Comment: I also need to pass a string to categoryclicked. how can i do it in this way? for now I am passing it this way onPress={this.categoryClicked.bind(this, subCategory)}

Comment: This is slightly harder to achieve and especially if your categories can change. I would suggest not trying to optimize this unless necessary. But if you really want to do it, something I have done is in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

this in `onPress={()=>this.categoryClicked.bind(this)}>` points to sub_category.map function. It should instead point to the class. Can be done this way instead

```
return (
  this.props.Category.sub_category.map((subCategory, i) => { // <--- this way context is preserved 
    // other lines
    onPress={()=>this.categoryClicked.bind(this, subCategory)}>
    // other lines
  })
);
```

in `categoryClicked` method should be accessible

```
categoryClicked(category){
    this.props.categoryPressed(category);
}
```

Comment: if i don't keep a return after map((subCategory, i) => {........ it does not return any view. and if i keep a return there, clicking on the text doesnot call the categoryClicked function

Comment: the return should be there. I'm just showing an example

Comment: Ok. And i think we also need to remove () => from the onpress

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. If you dont have to do anything else onPress. Something like this `onPress={this.categoryClicked.bind(this, subCategory)}`